# Loop into next column of Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, ultrawingrid

I am using foreach to loop into a grid by columns and while looping into one column i have to do a validation and loop into next visible column which is the validation and reset the image of the cell of the column.

//Code

```
            For Each col In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns

                If (col.Hidden = False) Then

                    'Get the first cell of the first column in the grid
                    cell= row.Cells(col.Index)

                    'Set the cell image
                    cell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
                    cell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
                    cell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top


                    'Loop in to the next visible column and reset the image of the cell
                        //Code here
                    cell= row.Cells(UltraGridColumn.Index + 1)

                    'Reset the cell image
                    cell.Appearance.ResetImage()

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do not call these variables with the same name of the class (UltraGridColumn, UltraGridRow, UltraGridCell). It is extremely confusing. And what is the problem with your actual code?

Comment: This works fine but i need to modify like if the loop in currently in the second column i need to loop the 3rd column parallely and make the cell reset.

Comment: Let me understand. You need to loop on every ROW and if the value in the second column of the current row is something not valid reset the image present in the third column of the current row?

Comment: The main logic is, I have to set the image in first column for some rows under certain conditions and if the user makes the column hidden the images set in the column should be moved to the first column which is visible now. if he revokes the column to visible the image should move back again. Am i clear?

Answer (score 0):

So supposing the ActiveRow is the row that you want to update this code will set your image in the first cell of the ActiveRow that is not hidden

```
For Each col In Me.TransactionsGrid.ActiveRow.Band.Columns
     UltraGridCell cell= row.Cells(col)
     If (col.Hidden = True) Then
         cell.Appearance.ResetImage();
     else              
        cell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
        cell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
        cell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top
        Exit For
     End If            
Next
```

You can also control the loop using a standar for...next and an indexer

```
For x = 0 To Me.TransactionsGrid.ActiveRow.Band.Columns.Count - 1
     UltraGridColumn col = Me.TransactionsGrid.ActiveRow.Band.Columns(x)
     UltraGridCell cell= row.Cells(col)
     If (col.Hidden = True) Then
         cell.Appearance.ResetImage();
     else              
        cell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
        cell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
        cell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top
        Exit For
     End If            
Next
```

This second approach has the benefit to allow you to change the start index in the column collection (something line `for x = 1 to Me.TransactionsGrid.ActiveRow.Band.Columns.Count - 1` )

Comment: I am getting images in both the columns. but i need only in the first column of the grid which is visible.

Comment: When the user selects both the columns to be visible i have to bind into the first column and remove the second. like wise there are 4 columns which can be made visible and invisible